# Blender - Inserting a line of text using bpy

Tags: user-interface, blender, bpy

I'm designing a simple GUI for a Blender 2.80 plug-in. I've created a dialog box to enter some data:

[image]

```
class ExportFDSCloudHPC(Operator):

    bl_idname = "..."
    bl_label = "Dialog Box"
    bl_description = "..."

    data1 = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = "Data 1",
        default = "..."
    )

    data2 = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = "Data 2",
        default = "..."
    )

    data3 = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = "Data 3",
        default = "..."
    )
    
    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column(align = True)
        col.prop(self, "data1")

        col = self.layout.column(align = True)
        col.prop(self, "data2")

        col = self.layout.column(align = True)
        col.prop(self, "data3")

    def execute(self, context):
        ...
```

I would like to add a line of text above Data 1 with a message that has the same length as the dialog box. It's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `label()` in `draw()` as you adding column:

```
def draw(self, context):
    self.layout.label(text="text")
    col = self.layout.column(align = True)
```

Here is [label documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.UILayout.label)